# Blender Fluid Simulator

Tags: fluid-simulation

I created a fountain and added a fluid simulator but when i tried to bake it. It started baking but the nothing happened to the domain or any of the object. I tried many things as reducing or increasing the size or increasing the resolution, applying the scale but the baking isn't actually taking place it just the domain and everything stays exactly the same. The bar on the top of the page also started loading with the tag baking but nothings happening as if no fluid or stuff is added. Its the blender 2.76 version as my computer doesn't support the newer version.

Comment: it could be something wrong in the setup, maybe, please add more details and a screenshot to show your fountain with domain and emitter, settings...

Comment: As first: use latest Blendev 2.79b. Sometimes I have also this trouble. I thing it's related to cache. You can try delete fluid cache manually. If doesn't help, you need to delete domain and create new one. Also delete cache files. This work for me. And file must be saved before baking.